# Android Create MP4 with bitmap series and mp3 by FFmpeg (i need minimal ffmpeg config for build)

Tags: android, linux, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

i'm building ffmpeg for android. my target is only **create mp4 video with series of bitmap image and merge mp3 audio**. i want use ffmpeg only only for this target. So i need optimized config for this target. i try find in google and find not bad config list. but i need full optimize config for reduce size of ffmpeg in android app. can you suggest me best config for this target?

i find this:

[Minimal configuration for mp4 files](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=1663)

[how do i modify this ffmpeg build script for minimal binary size output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832052/how-do-i-modify-this-ffmpeg-build-script-for-minimal-binary-size-output)

but is not complete optimized.

please suggest me full optimize config for my target. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These types of questions are not trivial as they seem so each question like this requires a custom answer. You must negotiate the spiderweb of internal and external dependencies, so you will likely need to experiment by compiling and testing multiple times until you get it right. Here's something to start with:

```
./configure --disable-all --disable-autodetect --disable-network --enable-pthreads
    --enable-avcodec --enable-avformat --enable-swscale --enable-swresample
    --enable-avfilter --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-parser=bmp,mpegaudio
    --enable-demuxer=image2,bmp_pipe,mp3 --enable-decoder=bmp --enable-muxer=mp4
    --enable-encoder=libx264 --enable-filter=format,scale --enable-protocol=file
    --enable-ffmpeg
```

- I probably forgot something.
- Memorize the output of `./configure --help`.
- Divine the innards of the `configure` file for clues.
- This does not include anything special or extra to get it to work on Android.
- It may be easier for users to avoid `--disable-all` and use `--disable-everything` instead. The first option disables components (muxers, demuxers, filters, decoders, encoders, etc), libraries, and programs. The second option "only" disables components.
- The resulting binary will be small, but if for some crazy reason file size is more important than speed consider adding `--enable-small`.
- MP3 is not as widely compatible as AAC in MP4.

Comment: `--enable-libx264` need to compile [x264](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html) or no need?

Comment: thanks for reply. i want only create standard mp4 video from bitmaps(images) and merge with audio(mp3). so i need to x264? (standard means: play on all devices and other OS.. without bug)

Comment: @grizzly MP4 is a container format. Most MP4 files contain H.264 video. You need x264 if you want to encode H.264 video via ffmpeg. There are other H.264 encoders available for use with ffmpeg but they are either worse and/or require specific hardware (none currently for Android as far as I know), so it's not worth using them in this case.

Comment: so i need specify compile `x264` ---> `--enable-libx264` and `lame` ---> `--enable-demuxer=mp3`. is true?

Comment: @grizzly Yes for x264. You don't need to compile lame because with `-c:a copy` you can just mux the existing MP3 audio into the MP4 output without needing to re-encode it. You do need the mp3 demuxer in ffmpeg, but that's part of ffmpeg, so you don't need to install anything extra for that: just enable it as shown in the example in the answer.

Comment: `LordNeckbeard` thank you. also `--disable-autodetect` not found command in ffmpeg configure.

Comment: can you help me my question on superuser: [https://superuser.com/questions/1256553/android-ffmpeg-create-mp4-with-bitmaps-no-jpg](https://superuser.com/questions/1256553/android-ffmpeg-create-mp4-with-bitmaps-no-jpg)

Comment: hi bro. thank you for answer on superuser. i can not cm on super user.(low reputation). my `img%03d.bmp` is not save on hardware for use. i have dynamic generate bitmap into variable. what is means: `"*.bmp"`?

Comment: my bitmaps (frames) generete on loop.

Comment: Do I have to generate all the files I've save to disk first? after use pattern? my frames are very large count. perhaps 2000 frames for 1 minutes video

Comment: @grizzly I was wondering about that actually. Can you pipe out from whatever is creating the images? If yes, then ffmpeg can use the pipe as input without you needing to create images.

Comment: how to use pipe? i have not image(jpg) on disk. i use generate bitmap via android method [Bitmap.createBitmap()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html).

Comment: `pipe:` is nice solution. I really appreciate your help. :x

Comment: yes. i recomplie with pipe and file. thanks my bro :x

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156037/discussion-between-grizzly-and-lordneckbeard).

Comment: hi bro. what is need configure for this two commands? cmd1-----> `ffmpeg -y -framerate 1 -start_number 1 -i img%4d.jpg -i mp3file.mp3 -s 800x800 -c:v libx264 -tune zerolatency -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -movflags +faststart -c:a aac -strict experimental -shortest output.mp4` cmd2-----> `ffmpeg -ss 10 -t 30 -i mp3file.mp3 -acodec copy output.mp3`. with `disable-all`. i no need other ffmpeg featureds. only need this command. so i need very small compile. thanks

Comment: @grizzly `make distclean; ./configure --disable-all --disable-autodetect --disable-network --enable-pthreads --enable-avcodec --enable-avformat --enable-swscale --enable-swresample --enable-avfilter --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-parser=mjpeg,mpegaudio --enable-demuxer=image2,mp3 --enable-decoder=mjpeg,mp3 --enable-muxer=mp3,mp4 --enable-encoder=aac,libx264 --enable-filter=aresample,format,resample,scale --enable-protocol=file --enable-ffmpeg && make ffmpeg` Make sure to add `-map a` to your second command to ignore any album cover. If you want to keep it add PNG and MJPEG stuff.

Comment: `--enable-demuxer=image2` really need? i not use this in command.

Comment: and exists option for faster execute? because the output render (cmd1) lasts a lot. for 1 minutes output about 3-4min

Comment: @grizzly [Let us continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156037/discussion-between-grizzly-and-lordneckbeard).

Comment: hi bro. please open room for chat. i need help

Comment: hi, is possible? [https://superuser.com/questions/1257322/convert-ffmpeg-command-to-ffmpeg-c-api-for-android-jni] (https://superuser.com/questions/1257322/convert-ffmpeg-command-to-ffmpeg-c-api-for-android-jni)

Comment: @grizzly Sorry, I don't know the answer to that. I don't know C++ or very much about Android. That question may get closed or migrated to Stack Overflow because it may involve programming.

Comment: i banned on stackoverflow. cannot add question.

Comment: `
You have reached your question limit
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.
`

Comment: i need [FFmpeg API Document](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/index.html) for convert command to c lang. is it possible? for adnroid NDK

Comment: @grizzly Yes, but I have no experience doing that. You may try asking how on the libav-user mailing list. It is the mailing list for questions about how to use the FFmpeg libraries.
http://ffmpeg.org/contact.html
Also see the examples in the source code in `doc/examples`. FFmpeg is written in C.

Comment: "add question" opened. thanks. ffmpeg api lib is very complex. i have a problem on this cmd: `ffmpeg -y -framerate 1 -start_number 1 -i img%4d.jpg -i mp3file.mp3 -s 800x800 -c:v libx264 -tune zerolatency -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -movflags +faststart -c:a aac -strict experimental -shortest output.mp4`. problem: when output mp4 play on some players, on change seekbar by user, seekbar is not smooth. is lag and skip. why?

Comment: and other problem: if i remove `-c:a aac` and replace `-acodec copy`. output mp4 have not sound on ios phones and some android low api phones. if use `-c:a aac` fix. why?

Comment: hi, can you help me? [this my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48645013/4910154)