# FFmpeg drawtext pts gmtime not working

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I use this command filter on ubuntu 16.4 with php `exec` to run:

```
drawtext=fontfile='$local_font_light':text='%{pts\:gmtime\:0\:%M\\\:%S}':fontcolor='#ffffff':fontsize=26:shadowcolor='#000000':shadowx=2:shadowy=2:x=620:y=(685-text_h), fade=t=in:st=2.5:d=1,fade=t=out:st=55:d=1[fadeDuration]
```

when run no error. but **not showing** on overlay.

**NOTE: this is fix on windows cmd. i use ffmpeg `3.4`**

i try this [answers](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/22590), but not working.

why?

Comment: Does it work if you run the `ffmpeg` command manually, unscripted in a command-line interface on your Ubuntu computer?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard yes. ffmpeg is fix and render success with complex filters. only this drawtext not show elapsed time.

Comment: If it is working in cli then I guess it is a PHP problem which I know nothing of.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard i print (echo in php) string command before execute, this `'%{pts\:gmtime\:0\:%M\\\:%S}'` convert to `'%{pts\:gmtime\:0\:%M\\:%S}'`.